# Porting cloud account information from ES Explorer

Tags: google-drive, cloud, es-file-explorer

I've been a pretty satisfied user of ES Explorer. When I wanted to add my MEGA cloud account I took the bait and paid for the pro version.

Problem is, their Google Drive (as well as DropBox) interaction is outdated. Google doesn't allow its authentication page to be loaded in a webview of another app. Now I can't add Google Drive to the new app.

The pro version is not an update up the ad-supported; it's another app. I still have Google Drive set up in the ad-supported app. How can I transfer the settings and account info from the old to the new? I do have root access and I've come across a file with the account information. I copied it over but it still doesn't show.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you copied the following file:`Gdrive.cfg` from `/data/data/com.estrongs.android.pop/files/` (permissions -rw) from the old app o new app?, This  config file contains the login token. Howver I think additional files with `gdrive` name need to be copied as well e.g `es_gdrive*`

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Thanks. I had already copied the .cfg file and now I copied the es_gdrive files as well, to no avail. I even copied serverlistdb7.xml from the shared_prefs folder.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Actually, it looks like that did indeed do the trick. It worked after a reboot. Exiting the app and clearing the state wasn't enough -- not sure why. Thanks.

Comment: No problem perhaps you can post this answer for other users who need to solve the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working was to copy the *.cfg files from the data\data\com.estrong.android.pop\files folder, and the serverlistdb*.xml files from the shared_prefs folder. Then, after a reboot the accounts showed up.